# unix: get all numeric values, including non-integers

Tags: unix, awk, numeric

I have a tab-delimited file where missing values are represented with a dot. For example:

```
VAR1    VAR2    VAR3    VAR4
ID1     foo     0.1     0.1
ID2     foo     1       1
ID3     foo     foo     .
ID4     foo     foo     foo
ID5     foo     .       1
ID6     foo     -0.1    -0.1
ID7     foo     -1      -1
ID8     foo     5e-08   5e-08
```

I need to extract all rows where the value in the third column is either numeric (including non-integer, negative values, scientific notation) or missing. So my output should look like this:

```
VAR1    VAR2    VAR3    VAR4
ID1     foo     0.1     0.1
ID2     foo     1       1
ID5     foo     .       1
ID6     foo     -0.1    -0.1
ID7     foo     -1      -1
ID8     foo     5e-08   5e-08
```

So far, I've tried doing this in awk using 
`awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} ( $3 ~ /^[[:alnum:]]+$/ ) {$1=$1; print}'` but then I only get

```
VAR1    VAR2    VAR3    VAR4
ID2     foo     1       1
```

I'd also like to save the rows that do not match (i.e. are non-numeric and not missing) in a separate file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How bow dah:

```
$ awk '$3*1==$3 || $3=="." || NR==1' file
VAR1    VAR2    VAR3    VAR4
ID1     foo     0.1     0.1
ID2     foo     1       1
ID5     foo     .       1
ID6     foo     -0.1    -0.1
ID7     foo     -1      -1
```

Explained:

- `NR==1` we're dealing with the header record
- `||` or
- `$3=="."` third field is a period
- `||` or
- `$3*1==$3` third field multiplied by one is still the same value

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. Even when I later realized some values were in scientific notation

Answer (score 2):

try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'NR==1{print;next} $3 !~ /[a-zA-Z]/' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk 'NR==1{print;next} $3 ~ /[0-9]/'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks, they both worked great for the example I initially provided, but I then realized my data has some values in scientific notation.

Comment: The first would incorrectly match `:-)` while the second would incorrectly match `Joe90`.